# Converting LCC crs to another format

Tags: python, coordinate-system, proj, pyproj

I collected metadata about POIs which I want to visualize. The original data however makes use of a projected CRS ("LCC projection") which I want to transform to lat/lon (WGS84):

```
"crs": "LCCprojection",
    "crsArg": {
        "lat_1": 46.12,
        "lat_2": 46.12,
        "center_lon": 14.815,
        "center_lat": 90,
        "x_0": -95410,
        "y_0": 6081340,
        "width": 5.67,
        "height": 4.3
    },
```

Unfortunately I don't have more information about the snippet above, i.e. the underlying datum etc.

I tried to transform the coordinates, but the resulting coordinates are way off:

```
import pyproj

lat_1=46.12
lat_2=46.12
center_lon=14.815
center_lat=90
x_0=-95410
y_0=6081340

projstr = f"+proj=lcc +lat_1={lat_1} +lat_2={lat_2} +lat_0={center_lat} +lon_0={center_lon}  +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
print(projstr)
# +proj=lcc +lat_1=46.12 +lat_2=46.12 +lat_0=90 +lon_0=14.815  +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

source = pyproj.Proj(projstr)
print(source(x_0,y_0,inverse=True))
# (126.3370956536579, 46.67898640154669)
```

Since the POI is located in Maribor (Slovenia) I expect the lat/long values to be roughly around 45 and 15 degrees.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Isn't `x_0` and `y_0` the false easting and false northing of the projection? You are using these values as the coordinates of your POI, but your proj string doesn't contain the false easting and false northing parameters. With the following proj string: `+proj=lcc +lat_1=46.12 +lat_2=46.12 +lon_0= 14.815 +lat_0=90 +x_0=-95410 +y_0=6081340 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs` the grid origin (0,0) translates to `(16.0620130176, 46.6789864015)` as longitude / latitude, which is somewhere in Northeastern Slovenia in the Murska Sobota region.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It helped me to get the function calls right. Something is still not right though. Some of the coordinates are relatively close  (on the order of  a few km), others are much further away. Do you have an idea which of the underlying  `proj` parameters could be tweaked?

Comment: Is it a consistent shift? If so, then you could always tweak the false easting and false northing parameters. Or is there a rotation or scale problem with the points? Which linear unit is used for the points? Meters, feet? Do they appear smaller/bigger than they should, or rotated?) Proj uses meters by default, so if for instance your points' coordinates are actually in feet, then that could be the cause of a scale problem.